# Are there some JS events for HTML attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that `document.createAttribute('myAttr')` creates an instance of the `Attr` class, both in FF and Chrome. I also noticed that `Attr` inherits from the `EventTarget` class, it expose all the `*EventListener` function indeed.

But I've never heard of attribute related event so if they trigger events, what events do they trigger? and when?

Comment: Probably, essentially a design bug. Per the spec: *If designed today they would just have a name and value. ☹* There isn't much use for an Attr to begin with AFAIK

Comment: @CertainPerformance in certain cases it's actually needed to have access the attribute node, not so much in HTML, but in XML you may have NameSpace wars inside your doc and several attributes sharing the same "name" on a same element. There having an Attr interface is *very* convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It inherits the `EventTarget` interface from [its `Node` inheritance](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node).
Various Nodes have events firing at them, `Attr` don't have any "built-in", but since they are Nodes, they also expose EventTarget's methods.

But as with every EventTarget, you can `dispatchEvent()` any Event you like manually.